# When I go to Localhost and try the username and the password it tells me that is an error?

Tags: php, security, passwords, md5

When I go to Localhost and try the username and the password it tells me that is an error? why?

Comment: your table name and database name is my_db ? is this correct ?

Comment: well, how did you save the password into db? (and by the way, you should _not_ md5 it. Use password_hash)

Comment: use `mysqli_error` to find out whats wrong. [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: yes! @JYoThI ...

Comment: @Jeff password: abc123

Comment: I will try it  @Jeff

Comment: try my answer @new_user

Comment: I tried it and tell me the same error! @JYoThI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks entered username/password or both are not matching with the database table my_db.

Reasons :
Localhost means the db is getting refereed in local. So in your local database under my_db table there is no user exists with the given username and password.
May be that data is valid in remote database server.

Solution :
1. Take a dump from remote database and put in your localhost so that your local db and remote db are replica
2. For simple solution, just insert the required details in my_db table.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

1) Use password_hash [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

while registration use `password_hash()` to hash the password and store it in database and while login use `password_verify()` to verify the password like this .

2) user prepared statement to avoid sql injection

```
<?php
   session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
    header("location: /web/home.php");
   }
if(isset($_POST["s"])){
   $username = $_POST["un"];
   $password = $_POST["ps"];

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db") or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());


$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username=?");

$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);

$stmt->execute();
$get_result =$stmt->get_result();

$row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

if($row_count>0)
{
    $record = $get_result->fetch_assoc();
    if(password_verify($password,$record['password']))
    {
    $_SESSION["user_id"]= $record["user_id"];
    header("location: /web/home.php");
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<h3 style = 'color:red'>Error in username or password</h3>";
    }

}else{
    echo "<h3 style = 'color:red'>Error in username or password</h3>";
}
 }
?>
```

Comment: use `password_hash()` on registration page and use `password_verify()` on login page... make sure your password hash a length about 60 chars, or better 255 chars